# Query filter for created date

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Hi we need to create a Filter Query for Power Automate flow on a SharePoint list. In Get Items we would like to only return everything where created date is more than 10 days in the past.  I have tried from looking at other on line posts but can't seem to get the exact correct syntax. If you could suggest how to write this Query would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Powerusers thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/ODATA-Filter-for-date-that-s-4-days-old/m-p/420212#M48579); its requestor was performing a similar task as you.  Per the thread, in your existing flow you'd:

1. Add an action:  **Get past time**.  This action is available via the **Date Time** connector.
2. Update **Get items** action /**Filter Query**:  Created gt @(body('Get_past_time')

*If the date needs to be reformatted, I believe you may want to use a variable and the formatDateTime function.